# Extending/Overriding Laravel Validator Class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-8, laravel-validation

In Laravel 8.3, they introduced a new feature, ***stopOnFirstFailure*** which stops the validation entirely once a rule fails. I would want to use this feature in Laravel 7. Upon checking the ***vendor/laravel/framework/src/Validation/Validator.php*** of Laravel 8, I found that ***stopOnFirstFailure*** simply adds an if statement in the ***passes*** function of the ***Validator.php*** which breaks the validation loop if the protected variable ***stopOnFirstFailure*** is true. Would it be possible to implement these in Laravel 7 by extending/overiding the Validator.php class? I've been researching about extending core Laravel classes and stumbled across this [article](https://orobogenius.medium.com/extending-core-laravel-bindings-97f409140fc3) but it is a bit confusing since the article only showed how to override a specific function. In my case I need to declare a protected variable, override one function and declare one new function.

Laravel 8 Validator.php code:


Declaring variable:

```
/**
     * Indicates if the validator should stop on the first rule failure.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $stopOnFirstFailure = false;
```

***stopOnFirstFailure*** function:

```
  /**
     * Instruct the validator to stop validating after the first rule failure.
     *
     * @param  bool  $stopOnFirstFailure
     * @return $this
     */
    public function stopOnFirstFailure($stopOnFirstFailure = true)
    {
        $this->stopOnFirstFailure = $stopOnFirstFailure;

        return $this;
    }
```

***passes*** function:

```
/**
     * Determine if the data passes the validation rules.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes()
    {
        $this->messages = new MessageBag;

        [$this->distinctValues, $this->failedRules] = [[], []];

        // We'll spin through each rule, validating the attributes attached to that
        // rule. Any error messages will be added to the containers with each of
        // the other error messages, returning true if we don't have messages.
        foreach ($this->rules as $attribute => $rules) {
            if ($this->shouldBeExcluded($attribute)) {
                $this->removeAttribute($attribute);

                continue;
            }

            if ($this->stopOnFirstFailure && $this->messages->isNotEmpty()) {
                break;
            }

            foreach ($rules as $rule) {
                $this->validateAttribute($attribute, $rule);

                if ($this->shouldBeExcluded($attribute)) {
                    $this->removeAttribute($attribute);

                    break;
                }

                if ($this->shouldStopValidating($attribute)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT: Validator is used in my code by Form Request.
Sample of my code:

```
class UpdateRegistrationTagsRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected $stopOnFirstFailure = true;
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'product_id' => ['required'],
            'product.*.type' => ['required','distinct'],
            'product.*.value' => ['required'],
            'product' => ['bail', 'required', 'array', new CheckIfArrayOfObj, new CheckIfProductTypeExists($this->product_id)]
        ];
    }

    protected function failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)
    {
        $response = new JsonResponse(['api' => [
            'header' => [
                'message' => 'The given data is invalid', 
                'errors' => $validator->errors()->first()   
            ],
            'body' => ''
                ]], 422);

        throw new \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException($validator, $response);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Followed @thefallen's advice, here is what I did.
My CustomValidator.php class in CustomClass inside app directory:

```
<?php 

namespace App\CustomClass;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

class CustomValidator extends Validator
{
    /**
     * Indicates if the validator should stop on the first rule failure.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $stopOnFirstFailure = true;

     /**
     * Instruct the validator to stop validating after the first rule failure.
     *
     * @param  bool  $stopOnFirstFailure
     * @return $this
     */
    public function stopOnFirstFailure($stopOnFirstFailure = true)
    {
        $this->stopOnFirstFailure = $stopOnFirstFailure;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the data passes the validation rules.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes()
    {
        $this->messages = new MessageBag;

        [$this->distinctValues, $this->failedRules] = [[], []];

        // We'll spin through each rule, validating the attributes attached to that
        // rule. Any error messages will be added to the containers with each of
        // the other error messages, returning true if we don't have messages.
        foreach ($this->rules as $attribute => $rules) {
            if ($this->shouldBeExcluded($attribute)) {
                $this->removeAttribute($attribute);

                continue;
            }

            if ($this->stopOnFirstFailure && $this->messages->isNotEmpty()) {
                break;
            }

            foreach ($rules as $rule) {
                $this->validateAttribute($attribute, $rule);

                if ($this->shouldBeExcluded($attribute)) {
                    $this->removeAttribute($attribute);

                    break;
                }

                if ($this->shouldStopValidating($attribute)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return parent::passes();
    }
}
```

My ValidatorFactory inside CustomClass folder

```
<?php 

namespace App\CustomClass;
use Illuminate\Validation\Factory;
use App\CustomClass\CustomValidator;

class ValidatorFactory extends Factory
{
    protected function resolve( array $data, array $rules, array $messages, array $customAttributes )
    {
        if (is_null($this->resolver)) {
            return new CustomValidator($this->translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
        }

        return call_user_func($this->resolver, $this->translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
    }
}
```

My AppServiceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\CustomClass\ValidatorFactory;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->extend('validator', function () {
            return $this->app->get(ValidatorFactory::class);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add code how you currently use the Validator? Do you have a Request class or you call it manually?

Comment: @thefallen Hi, added my code. Thank you.

Comment: `Would it be possible to implement these in Laravel 7 by extending/overiding the Validator.php class?` Yes, I guess that was your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically need to extend the Validator to make changes on that method and then make your own Validation Factory to create this new Validator instead of the default one. So step one with you own validator:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class CustomValidator extends Validator
{
    public function passes()
    {
        //TODO make changes on that loop
        return parent::passes();
    }
}
```

Then you need a Validation Factory which will be creating this new class, this will also extend the default one:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Factory;

class ValidatorFactory extends Factory
{
    protected function resolve( array $data, array $rules, array $messages, array $customAttributes )
    {
        if (is_null($this->resolver)) {
            return new CustomValidator($this->translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
        }

        return call_user_func($this->resolver, $this->translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
    }
}
```

Finally inside `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` in the `register()` method you need to swap the default factory with your custom one:

```
$this->app->extend('validator', function () {
    return $this->app->get(ValidatorFactory::class);
});
```

Note that `validator` is the name of the binding (or alias) of `Illuminate\Validation\Factory`. And you should be good to go and be able to make any changes on the validator.

Comment: Thanks for your response @thefallen. I tried what you suggested, I created a folder in my app directory called CustomClass then made two classes CustomValidator.php and ValidatorFactory.php. I copied the Laravel 8 code in the CustomValidator.php and copied your code for both ValidatorFactory and registered the factory in the AppServiceProvider but it doesn't seem to work, I'm not getting any errors though.

Comment: @cjdy13, that is strange, because this should work for form requests and manual validation if you follow the steps. Anyway, this other solution I didn't want to suggest is having a `validator()` method in your Form Request class and there you can return your class `app(CustomValidator::class)` from there. Downside is this will be called only for this Form Request.

Comment: let me update my post so I could show you exactly what I did.

Comment: I updated my post with the current code. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @thefallen, my bad, the passes function that I copied was not complete, I just copied the missing piece of code and now it works! Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: @thefallen, your solution apears to be easy to implement, but I get an exception message: **Presence verifier has not been set.**.

Comment: The exception is thrown when I use rule like "unique" or "exists".

Comment: To avoid use of factories, alternative syntax is at https://medium.com/@melihovv/how-to-reuse-laravel-validator-internal-methods-in-your-custom-validation-rules-14acc5e270e5 for inside the `AppServiceProvider::register()` method:
`$this->app['validator']->resolver(function ($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) { return new Validator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages); });` also `validateExists()` and `validateUnique()` can be overridden without having to create a `passes()` method, you can find the originals in `Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\ValidatesAttributes`

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late, but I had same issue stuck on Laravel 6.
didn't want to extend/override current normal behavior for the validator.
So I did this

```
public function validateResolved()
{
    if (!$this->authorize()) {
        $this->failedAuthorization();
    }
    foreach ($this->rules() as $key=>$val) {
        $validator = app('validator')->make(
            request()->all(),
            [$key=>$val],
            $this->messages()
        );
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            throw \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::withMessages($validator->errors()->messages());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer from user @davestewart from laracasts:

> The supposed correct way of using (resolving) custom validators is to use the `Validator::resolver` method:
>
> ```
> App::make('validator')->resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
> {
>     // return your custom validator here
>     return new MyCustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
> });
> ```
>
> In theory, when the `FormRequest` class calls `getValidatorInstance()` it should resolve your custom validator.

My personal feeling is that it's a really fragile way to do things, but I've only been using the framework 9 months or so, so I assume there are good reasons to make it this - frankly - convoluted.

P.S. The implementation was tested on a commercial project and fully satisfied the requirements.